# Using My FMXL file from JavaFx Scene builder file

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx-2, scenebuilder

So this is my 3rd question on this topic (sorry for the spam)

so far i have installed e(fx)clipse, i have installed JavaFx Scene builder, i have created a test GUI with the Scene builder which i have saved into a file named "test", i have added that file into my SRC and now i want to run the program with my GUI but the file that i have copied is an fxml file. How do i import it into my "Main" and run it as my GUI?

Also how do i use the buttons (i have given the 2 buttons i have created as ID: Button1 and Button2) im used to the old eclipse GUI builder with the actionListners, but does anyone know how it works in JavaFx Scene builder (when its imported into the program)?

Hope someone is able to help me since it is really hard finding guides made for eclipse on the internet :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some steps to try:

1. Create a new JavaFX project in e(fx)clipse.
2. Create a JavaFX Application class and in the start method place the following code:

   ```
   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_example.fxml"));

       stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
       stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
       stage.show();
   }
   ```
3. Include a sample fxml file in your project (eg fxml_example.fxml) in the same directory as your application source.
4. Make sure that eclipse is copying the file fxml file to your build output directory.
5. Run your project - your application should now display the fxml gui.

Even though it's written for NetBeans, I advise following the tutorial [Getting Started with JavaFX: Using FXML to Create a User Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm). File a new ticket in the [e(fx)clipse bug tracker](http://efxclipse.org/trac/newticket) if you would like the e(fx)clipse project to create an eclipse specific version of this getting started document.

You will probably get a better response to your eclipse+javafx specific questions in the [e(fx)clipse forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/efxclipse).

Here is another [tutorial on wiring up SceneBuilder generated fxml and Java code](https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_scenebuilder_edited_fxml_to).  Note that this wiring is not IDE specific - current IDEs neither help nor hinder in this task.